# How removing dragged element only if it has a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove a dragged element, but it should only be removed when it doesn't have the class "nodrop".

here's my current code it removes all elements wheter i included an if function:

```
    $(".löschen").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("nodrop")){
    ui.draggable.remove();
    findTotal();
    }
    }});
```

I don't have any plan what I've done wrong...

Comment: try with a class without "umlauts"

Comment: Or do you want something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp

Comment: @ppasler why? how would that help?

Comment: @Jolp: Where are you stuck? [The jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) quite clearly gives simple utility functions to do things like determine if an element has a particular class, and JavaScript has an `if` statement like nearly all other programming languages...

Comment: @ppasler: From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier): *"In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_)...Note that Unicode is code-by-code equivalent to ISO 10646 (see [UNICODE] and [ISO10646])."* `ö` is U+00F6, so it's fine.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're right, my bad - it's just that Umlaute always makes me nervous :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You get the current drop container (`.löschen`) with `$(this)`. With `$(ui.draggable)` you get the dropped element with class `nodrop`.

```js
$(".draggable").draggable();

$(".löschen").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var $dropContainer = $(this);
    var $dragContainer = $(ui.draggable)
    console.log($dropContainer, $dragContainer);
    if (!$dragContainer.hasClass("nodrop")){
      $dragContainer.remove();
    }
}});
```

```
.draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.drop {
  background-color: green;
}

.nodrop {
  background-color: red;
}

.löschen {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="draggable nodrop">NO DROP</div>
<div class="draggable drop">DROP</div>

<div class="löschen">TRASH</div>
```

Comment: No it doesn't work even if I relpace "element.remove()" with "ui.draggable.remove();"

Comment: @Jolp sorry I got you wrong, I hope I understood you right this time :)

Comment: Thank you i'll try a test the next year :D